# How to root MK 809 iii?

Tags: root-access

I have an Android MK809 III stick and I am looking to root it, to run apps with super user permissions. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a step by step guide:

1. Connect the DC micro-usb port to power, and the other micro-usb port to your computer.
2. Go to Settings USB and select the checkbox for "Connect to PC"
3. Run KingoRoot to root the phone.
4. Download SuperSu.apk
5. load /system partition in read/write mode with:
   `adb shell "su -c mount -o remount,rw /system"`
6. adb push SuperSu.apk /system/app/SuperSu.apk